# Django populate Form from Model

Tags: python, django

Django 2.0.2

Python 3.6.3

Hi,

I am still trying to learn Python by jumping head first into a django project.  I have a "profile" model that extends the "user" model.  I have a `ModelForm` for the profile.  I have a `create` action that creates a new profile and saves it and the user info.  That all works.

I am trying to add the other `CRUD` actions and am starting with an "edit" method.  I have read the ["Creating forms from models"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) django doc.

I see their idiom of (copied form the link above):

```
    >>> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    ...     class Meta:
    ...         model = Article
    ...         fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']

    # Creating a form to add an article.
    >>> form = ArticleForm()

    # Creating a form to change an existing article.
    >>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
    >>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

In my code I am trying:

```
 1  def edit(request, pk):
 2      try:
 3          profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
 4
 5          if request.method == 'POST':
 6              form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
 7          else:
 8              form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
 9
10          if form.is_valid():
11              profile = form.save(commit=False)
12              profile.user = request.user
13              profile.save()
14              my_render = render(request, 'Members/index.html', {
15                  'profile': profile
16              })
17          else:
18              my_render = render(request, 'Members/profile.html', {
19                  'profileEdit': form,
20                  'profileState': "edit"
21              })
22      except Profile.DoesNotExist:
23          raise Http404("No Profile matches the given query.")
24
25      return my_render
```

So, in my debugger I can do an account creation.  I can then click a button that triggers this edit action.

Line #3: produces what appears to be (to my eye) a valid copy of the profile I want to edit.

Line #8 is the next line executed.  It produces a `form` object but it is not populated with the profile instance.

Line #18 is next because the form is obviously not valid.  the `render` generates missing value errors in the form.

Am I missing a step in which the form is populated with model data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to check if form is valid if request is POST.

Also i would suggest to look into Django CBV that are already perfectly structured and easy extendable.